# What is meant by "Then use it via SuperChart...", in the context of adding a custom (echart) to library of charts in superset?

Tags: customization, echarts, apache-superset

I would like to add a custom chart to Apache Superset. Though I understand that this application is under constant development, what exactly is meant by:

> Then use it via SuperChart...

```
<SuperChart
  chartType="echarts-basic-radar"
  width={600}
  height={600}
  formData={...}
  queryData={{
    data: {...},
  }}
/>
```

In for instance this page: https://github.com/huandzh/superset-ui-plugins-echarts-basic/tree/master/packages/superset-ui-preset-chart-echarts-basic

I completed all the other steps... still this step I did not understand. Can someone please explain how to add an echart? And what are the steps to do this? What is SuperChart?

Answer (score 0):

it's for demonstrating in the storybook